# Cannot save image file to server via PHP

Tags: php, html

there. I'm not very experienced with PHP, but I've been charged with modifying a site that is very heavy in PHP. Part of the functionality is uploading an image and having it display on the page. I have gotten the image name to write to the database and the image HTML to display when the database field is not empty. However, I cannot figure out how to get the image to save to the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    <label for="logo">Primary Logo Upload:</label> <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" class="fullWidth" ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
    <input type="hidden" name="logo" value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetCity['logo']; ?>" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {

    $location = $_FILES['logo'];
    $image = rand(1,2);
    $image = $image * time();
    $image = $image."-lp".".jpg";
    $filename = $image;
    $path="./_citylogo/logo/".$filename;
    $tempname=$location['tmp_name'];
    copy($tempname,$path);
    if ($location['name'] == "") {
        $_POST['logo'] = $_POST['logo'];
    } else {
       $_POST['logo'] = $image;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you write a question about an error, always __always__ include details of the error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: make sure you `$path="./_citylogo/logo/".$filename;` is writable

Comment: @NishanthMatha Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank youuu. That was the issue! Damn permissions.

Comment: no worries. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you `$path="./_citylogo/logo/".$filename;` is writable

Answer (score 2):

```
$tempname= $location['tmp_name'];
$name = $location['tmp_name'];
$folder_directory = 'foldername/';
$check_folder_exists = is_dir($folder_directory);

if(!$check_folder_exists){
    mkdir($folder_directory , 0755, true);
//create folder if it doesn't exists.
//0755 - the image file can be access for the owner, while other can read and execute it.

}

$file_directory = $folder_directory.$name;
$move_temp_file = move_uploaded_file($tempname, $file_directory);

//note: This next part is optional.
if($move_temp_file){
    chmod($file_directory, 644);
//chmod() change the image file so it can't to executable by other in your server incase some hacker, upload a bad image.
}
```